# Material-ui Button onClick to submit a Dialog is not updating FormData. FormData.append is not appending

Tags: reactjs, file, file-upload, material-ui, form-data

In this functionality, I am just uploading a file with some description field (containing some text) with the **[Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/)** component of Material-UI and capturing the file and related description string with **[FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)** with the below handleUpload function that will be triggered on Button onClick.

```
handleUpload = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append(
      "file",
      this.state.selectedFile,
      this.state.document_name,
      this.state.description
    );

    if (data.get("description") !== "" && data.get("document_name") !== "") {
      this.props
        .createGo(data, history)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("FORM DATA INSIDE", data);
          console.log("FILE IS ", this.state.selectedFile);
          this.setState({
            open: true,
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "center"
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status === 422) {
            alert(
              "File must be less than 10 MB and type must be one of pdf, jpeg, jpg, png, doc, xlx, xlsx, ppt pptx"
            );
          } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
            history.push("/login");
            alert("Please Login, session expired");
          }
        });
    } else {
      showEmptyFieldSnackbar();
      return false;
    }
  };
```

When I am NOT using Material-UI Dialog then the its working as expected. [The working code is here](https://gist.github.com/rohan-paul/3153818a79b1097583e8c1902202d0cc)

**But when I am using Material-UI to submit the dialog to uplaod the file, its not working because the FormData() remains empty. Note the line `console.log("FORM DATA INSIDE", data);` is giving me an empty FormData. That is, the following code**

```
const data = new FormData();
    data.append(
      "file",
      this.state.selectedFile,
      this.state.document_name,
      this.state.description
    );
```

is NOT appending anything.

And here is my full component, using Material-UI to submit the dialog

```
class GoCreateForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      document_name: "",
      description: "",
      selectedFile: null,
      open: false,
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "center",
      dialogOpen: false
    };
  }

  // and below handleClose function as well is for closing snackbar
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
    history.push("/dashboard/gos");
  };

  handleSelectedFile = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: e.target.files[0]
    });
  };

  handleUpload = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append(
      "file",
      this.state.selectedFile,
      this.state.document_name,
      this.state.description
    );

    if (data.get("description") !== "" && data.get("document_name") !== "") {
      this.props
        .createGo(data, history)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("FORM DATA INSIDE", data);
          console.log("FILE IS ", this.state.selectedFile);
          this.setState({
            open: true,
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "center"
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status === 422) {
            alert(
              "File must be less than 10 MB and type must be one of pdf, jpeg, jpg, png, doc, xlx, xlsx, ppt pptx"
            );
          } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
            history.push("/login");
            alert("Please Login, session expired");
          }
        });
    } else {
      showEmptyFieldSnackbar();
      return false;
    }
  };

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: false
    });
  };

  handleEnterEscapeKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.onSubmit();
    } else if (e.key === "Escape") {
      this.handleCancel();
    }
  };

  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: !this.state.dialogOpen
    });
  };

  handleFabOpen = () => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      vertical,
      horizontal,
      open,
      document_name,
      description,
      selectedFile
    } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <FormControl>
          <div>
            <Fab
              onClick={this.handleFabOpen}
              aria-pressed="true"
              color="secondary"
              size="large"
              aria-label="Add"
              fontSize="large"
              className={classes.fabButton}
            >
              <AddIcon />
            </Fab>

            <Dialog
              open={this.state.dialogOpen}
              onClose={this.handleToggle}
              aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
              fullWidth={true}
              maxWidth={"sm"}
              variant="contained"
              PaperProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes.paper
                }
              }}
              onKeyDown={this.handleEnterEscapeKeyPress}
            >
              <form onSubmit={this.handleUpload}>
                <DialogTitle
                  id="form-dialog-title"
                  disableTypography
                  className={classes.dialogTitleAdd}
                >
                  <div className={classes.displayFlexDialogTitle}>
                    <Typography
                      variant="h5"
                      className={classes.dialogTitleHeading}
                    >
                      Upload a new Government Order
                    </Typography>
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={this.handleToggle}
                      className={classes.button}
                      style={{ float: "right" }}
                    >
                      <CancelIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </div>
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent required>
                  <div style={{ display: "flex", margin: "auto" }}>
                    <TextField
                      required
                      autoFocus
                      error={document_name === ""}
                      fullWidth
                      classes={{
                        root: classes.space
                      }}
                      type="string"
                      onChange={e => {
                        this.setState({
                          document_name: e.target.value
                        });
                      }}
                      value={document_name}
                      helperText={
                        document_name === ""
                          ? "Please enter Document Name"
                          : " "
                      }
                      label="Document Name"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ display: "flex", margin: "auto" }}>
                    <TextField
                      required
                      autoFocus
                      multiline={true}
                      error={description === ""}
                      fullWidth
                      classes={{
                        root: classes.space
                      }}
                      type="string"
                      onChange={e => {
                        this.setState({
                          description: e.target.value
                        });
                      }}
                      value={description}
                      helperText={
                        description === ""
                          ? "Please enter Document Description"
                          : " "
                      }
                      label="Document Description"
                    />
                  </div>
                  {selectedFile === null ? null : (
                    <div style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}>
                      {selectedFile.name}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <div
                    style={{ display: "flex", margin: "auto" }}
                    className="form-group"
                  >
                    <Button variant="contained" component="label">
                      Upload File
                      <input
                        type="file"
                        style={{ display: "none" }}
                        onChange={this.handleSelectedFile}
                      />
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions className={classes.dialogActions}>
                  <div className={classes.displayFlexDialogActions}>
                    <Button
                      onClick={this.handleCancel}
                      variant="contained"
                      size="small"
                      color="secondary"
                      className="float-right"
                      style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
                    >
                      <Link
                        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}
                        to="/dashboard/gos"
                      >
                        Cancel
                      </Link>
                    </Button>

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                      Upload
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </DialogActions>
              </form>
            </Dialog>
          </div>
        </FormControl>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

GoCreateForm.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { createGo }
)(withStyles(styles)(GoCreateForm));
```

Comment: Also, why is the `FormControl` in the Dialog?  Seems unnecessary right from the get go.

Comment: Start out by taking your working code, then just add the dialog wrapper to it with everything in the working example in the dialog content.  If the form submission works like that, start migrating functionality to the built-in dialog functionality one by one

Comment: Thanks @Jake, I could make it work going in this way